# Is there a way to create a parent and its child from arguments in one query in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, foreign-keys, mongoose-schema, nosql

Let's say I have a `Person` (collection `persons`) defined like that:

```
const personSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  children: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Person',
  }],
})
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema)
```

I can't store `children` directly inside a `Person`, because two objects can link to the same `child`, so that's why I am doing this via relation.

The thing is, let's say I want to create a `Person` and its `children` in one query. And I have an `args` object to get data from, defined like that:

```
const args = { name: 'John', children: [{ name: 'Anna' }, {name: 'Craig'}] }
```

I need a query to create 3 documents inside the `persons` collection, with names `John`, `Anna` and `Craig` and it also should record `Anna` and `Craig`'s `id`s inside `John`'s `children` field, like that:

```
{_id: 1, name: "John", children: [2, 3]}
{_id: 2, name: "Anna"}
{_id: 3, name: "Craig"}
```

I tried to pass this `args` to the create function like that:

```
Person.create(args)
```

and it complains about `children` array not being array of `ObjectId`s.

And I guess (didn't test it yet) if I replace `children`'s `type` with the `personSchema` instead, it will create a nested document instead, which I don't want.

So, the question is: is there a way in Mongoose to do what I want in one query? (I also know that I can do multiple queries to save every child then saving the parent, but something tells me that's not the way it should be done and that there should be an easier way to do this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following approach to insert such document:

Use collection insert query to insert an array of object:
**ex:**

```
PersonModel.collection.insert({ name: 'John', children: [{ name: 'Anna' }, {name: 'Craig'}] }, function() {
    console.log("insert person data");
});
```

Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e8da5e6be4d87da7824d29"),
    "name" : "John",
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Anna"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Craig"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to have _id with each subobject then you have to manually generate objectId using objectId constructor:

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
PersonModel.collection.insert({
    name: 'John',
    children: [{
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: 'Anna'
    }, {
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: 'Craig'
    }]
}, function() {
    console.log("insert person data");
});
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e8dcd76e620c680d850ebe"),
    "name" : "John",
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57e8dcd56e620c680d850eba"),
            "name" : "Anna"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57e8dcd56e620c680d850ebb"),
            "name" : "Craig"
        }
    ]
}
```

UPDATE:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

PersonModel.collection.insert([{
    name: 'Anna'
}, {
    name: 'Craig'
}], {
    ordered: true
}, function(err, data) {
    //console.log(data);
    var parent = {
        name: 'john',
        children: data.insertedIds
    };
    new PersonModel(parent).save()

});
```

Comment: This will create 1 nested document, and I need to create 3 separate documents

Comment: As you mentioned in your question there is no need to do save all children and parent using separate query. You can create all documents using same query but to set the children you have to hit another query. I'll update my answer for it.